# GetForegroundWindow() is not updating when new window is in front

Tags: winapi

I do this

```
HWND lParentWinHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, lArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,
    &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
{ ... }

// at this point a new window appears in the foreground.

HWND lChildWinHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
SetParent(lChildWinHandle , lParentWinHandle );
```

but lParentWinHandle and lChildWinHandle have the same value !

Comment: Please tell us what you ant to do...

Comment: obvioulsy I want to do : SetParent(lChildWinHandle , lParentWinHandle );

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that, although `CreateProcess()` appears to operate instantly, it's still not as quick as the time between `CreateProcess()` and `GetForegroundWindow()`.  I don't believe there's any reason to think that the `CreateProcess()` call is synchronous. If I'm right, then a dirty solution might be just to insert a small time delay. A more elegant method might be to call `EnumWindows()` in a loop until your "child" window's caption appears. However, I'm not sure how happy Windows is in general with having a window's parent-child relationship spanning processes.

Comment: This is brittle at best. CreateProcess is async and likely returns before the new window is created. The right approach is to use IPC to have the child tell the parent its main window handle. Finally though, you can't express cross process parent/child relationships to work. I don't expect you'll believe me, askers who ask try to do this on a daily basis seldom do.

Comment: What you are ultimately trying to accomplish is not in general supported. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: It is an XY problem. The owner asks for GetForegroundWindow, But he just want to get the handle of the new process... wrong question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the handle of the new process. You should use the process and thread handle of the PROCESS_INFO structure.

And according to the documentation you should wit with WaitForInputIdle until you start the search.

Code is similar to this (it is just a dirty sample no error checking):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumThreadWndProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
   hWndMain = hWnd; // got the main window...
   return FALSE; // ...stop enum
}

// ...
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo = {0};
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo = {0};

   CreateProcessA(NULL, pCmd, 
                  NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL,
                  &siStartInfo,&piProcessInfo);

   if(WaitForInputIdle(piProcessInfo.hProcess, 5000)==0)
   {
      EnumThreadWindows(piProcessInfo.dwThreadId, 
                            EnumThreadWndProc, NULL);
   }
   else
   {
      // Could not start program
      ...
   }
   // ...
```

But please read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: WaitForInputIdle isn't very reliable. Really the correct way is for the child process to send a message to the parent when the window is ready.